# Getting the "window" object for an eval, and list all vars? Javascript eval inline html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, eval, inline

Eval is generally disliked, but it seems necessary.

Currently, I have an ajax call that retrieves a html file that has inline javascript.  Then it gets the script by tagname and evals it.

This all works fine, but what I can't figure out is where all the vars go.

For instance, in a normal case, everything can be found in window:

```
var you = "buddy"
alert(window["you"]);
//Alerts : "buddy"
```

But when I do an eval, I don't know what the equivalent of 'window' is.  I'm not sure where all the vars end up.

What I would like is some way to get a list of all of them, without any of them overriding vars that exist in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later, I finally found the solution:

```
with (new Proxy()) { eval() }
```

The codebase I was working on is long dead, but that proxy will catch it all.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` will share the global context (`window`) and any local variables. If executed in global scope:

```
eval('var a=1; b=2');
console.log(window.a, window.b);
// => 1 2
```

`new Function` will create a new local scope:

```
new Function('var c=7; d=4')()
console.log(window.c, window.d);
// => undefined 4
```

You can enumerate any variables in global scope as properties of `window` (or `global`). You cannot enumerate local variables in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke `eval()` directly, then it runs in the local scope.  So, if the script defines new variables, then they are defined in the local scope.  There is no built-in way to iterate local scope variables as Javascript does not provide a way to iterate the variables defined within the local scope (unless the local scope happens to also be the global scope).

If you invoke `eval` via an indirect reference such as this:

```
var geval = eval;
geval("some code here");
```

Then, code is evaluated at the global scope and any variables defined within the script become new globals.

You can see this [explained on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Note: The rules are a bit different in [`strict` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
eval(console.log(this));
```

the response is the global window object, so the local scope of evals appears to be inaccessible.

EDIT:  It ends up the result is `undefined` as shown by DJDavid98:

```
eval("console.log('call resulted in: "+console.log(this)+"')");
```

You can make evals store variables globally in a few ways.  The first is by referencing the eval (as shown by @jfriend00) like so:

```
var geval = eval;
geval("some code here");
```

The other way of making a variable global is by removing the var from in front, like so:

```
eval("mrglobal = 'hey'; var local = 'can't find me'")
console.log(window["mrglobal"]); //outputs hey
console.log(window["local"]); //outputs undefined
```

Knowing this, a better solution can be found:

Here's some input and output:
INPUT:

```
var mrlocal = "hey neighbor";
mrglobal = "just passing through"

if(true) {
    mrlocal = mrglobal
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
var window.evals[0].mrlocal = "hey neighbor";
mrglobal = "just passing through"

if(true) {
    window.evals[0].mrlocal = mrglobal
}
```

And for the function: One can regex whatever they are about to eval and add global references for the local variables, like so:

```
var evalIndex = window.evals.length;
window.evals[evalIndex] = {};
var evalPrefix = "window.evals["+evalIndex+"].";

var localVars = [];

var scripts = initMe.getElementsByTagName("script");
for(var s = 0; s < scripts.length; s++)  {

    var rex = /(var.+(;|\n)|(\{(.|\n)+?\}))/g;
    var localVarRex = scripts[s].innerHTML.match(rex);

    for(i in localVarRex)  {
        var match = localVarRex[i];
        if(match.charAt(0) != '{') {
            var var_name = match.replace(/(var +|( ?)+=.+\n?)/g, '');

            var_name = var_name.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
            localVars.push(var_name);
        }
    }
}


console.log(localVars);


for(var s = 0; s < scripts.length; s++) {
    var textToEval = scripts[s].innerHTML;
    for(i in localVars)  {
        var match = localVars[i];
        var replace = evalPrefix+match;

        var rex = new RegExp("(var)?[^\.]"+match, "g");

        textToEval = textToEval.replace(rex, function(replaceMe) {
            var out = replaceMe;
            if(replaceMe.charAt(0) != '.') {
                console.log('match::"'+replaceMe+'"');
                out = replace;
                if(replaceMe.charAt(0) != 'v')
                    out = replaceMe.charAt(0)+replace;
            }
            return out;
        });

        eval(textToEval);

    }
}
```

So, with this trick, you can bring in outside html, eval it's scripts, and keep all the local variables.

Comment: The first eval you mention doesn't actually return the global window object, it runs `console.log(this)` in the scope it's in, then passes the result (`undefined`) of the call to `eval`. Try running `eval("console.log('call resulted in: "+console.log(this)+"')");` to see for yourself.